# Sort list elements belonging to enumerable object

Tags: python, django, enumerable

I have a list of possible types of products :

```
PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    (PRODUCT_UNISEX, _(u"Unisex")),
    (PRODUCT_MENS, _(u"Mens")),
    (PRODUCT_WOMANS, _(u"Womans")),
]
```

And a second list containing some Product objects.

```
all_products = [Product1, Product2, Product3, ..., ProductN]
```

Each product has a field/property for type choice :

```
type = models.CharField(_(u"Type"), max_length=15, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES, default=PRODUCT_UNISEX)
```

Now I'd like to enumerate PRODUCT_TYPE_CHOICES and create a list for each enumerable item that will contain it's name and amount of products (from all products) having type of enumerable :

```
ret = [['Unisex', 15],['Mens', 10],['Womans', 6]]
```

Currently I have this :

```
for i, v in enumerate(PRODUCT_RODZAJ_CHOICES):
    r = []
    r.append(v[1])
    ret.append(r)
```

so I'm lacking the amount of products for each type. I was trying to do this with lambda but currently without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 liner:

```
zip([sum(t) for t in zip( \
               *[(1,0,0) if p.type==PRODUCT_UNISEX \
                 else (0,1,0) if p.type==PRODUCT_MENS \
                 else (0,0,1) for p in products] \
                        ) \
    ], \
    ['Unisex','Mens','Womans'])
```

Or in a classic way:

```
dict = {}
for p in products:
    dict[p.get_type_display()] = 1 + dict.get(p.get_type_display(), 0)

ret = [[key,value] for key,value in dict.iteritems()]
```